# What am i doing wrong with Promise rejections here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, request-promise

So I've made a bit of reusable code here for node, and I'm applying it via async / await. Albeit I'm sure I am misunderstanding a lot here when working with this... But, I swear, I have one project I'm using this code that it works, and another where it doesn't.
Im using `request` and `request-promise`.

```
UrlRequest: function( opts ) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        request( opts, 
            function(error, request, body) {
                if (error) 
                    reject( {error: true, msg: error} );
                else
                    resolve( {body, request} );
            });
        })
        .catch(err => reject( {error: true, msg: err} ));
    }
```

I am fairly sure the `.catch()` is wrong. But it didn't error out in my 1st project. So i'm trying to figure out the proper way of doing this. The few articles I've looked through is where I came up with this function for usage. I also know if any error actually happens ( this case included ), it will throw a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error. So how is this properly handled?

How I use it:

```
(async () => {
var result = await Promise.UrlRequest( {
    url: "...",
    method: "GET",
    headers: DefaultHeaders
    } );

// do stuff with result... 

}) ();
```

Comment: If you’re using request-promise, why are you creating a promise manually from request? Doing all that for you – correctly – is the point of request-promise.

Comment: I would've thought request-promise requests don't take a callback

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error. So how is this properly handled?` by using a try/catch block, which you don't in `var result = await Promise.UrlRequest`

Comment: You're trying to use both a callback and a `.catch()`.   There is no form of `request()` that I know of that supports that.  For the `request()` library, it would be only the callback.  For the `request-promise()` library, it would be only `.then()` and `.catch()`, no callback at all.

Comment: @jfriend00: The indentation and reference to non-existent `reject` are misleading; `.catch()` is on `new Promise(…)`.

Comment: Well this is why I am asking here since I finally gave up trying to figure out my own issues after a couple weeks of looking around and trying new code myself. Since I wasn't getting anywhere.

Comment: @Ry - Yep, fooled by messed up indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already installed `request-promise`, you don't need constructing the `Promise` as you are doing. Simply use the it instead of `request` then you would have a promise returned. Something similar to this should work:

```
const request = require('request-promise')

request(opts)
    .then((res) => {
        // Process res...
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // Handle error...
    });
```

You can proceed to wrap it in your `UrlRequest` function and use with `async` as follows:

```
UrlRequest: async ( opts ) => {
  try {
    const response = await request(opts);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle error
  }
}
```

In the case that you want to use `then()` and `catch()`, you can do this:

```
UrlRequest: ( opts ) => {
  return request(opts)
            .then(response => response)
            .catch (error) {
              // Handle error
            }
}
```

Comment: Would it cause any problems putting the `.then()` and `.catch()` in my UrlRequest function? Its a module that will be re-used across a couple projects. But thanks for but use cases!

Comment: No it won't cause any problems. You can use `then()` and `catch()` instead of the try and catch block.

Answer (score 1):

With `request-promise`, you don't need to write your own `Promise` wrapper

```
// make sure you're using the promise version
const request = require('request-promise')

var opts = {
  ...
  resolveWithFullResponse: true    //  <---  <--- to get full response, response.body contains the body
};

// if you dont plan to use UrlRequest as constructor, better name is starting with lowercase: urlRequest, some naming convention
UrlRequest: async function( opts ) {
  let res;
  try {
    res = await request(opts);
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
    throw e
  }
  return res;
}
```

Note: `async` function wraps the return in `Promise`